# How can I update the date column when the another column is current date?

Tags: mysql

a need update the column handtool_last_date_of_maintenance to current date when the handtool_next_date_of_maintenance is current date. what is the exact syntax for this? thank you

table

```
|| *handtool_id* || *handtool_last_date_of_maintenance* || *handtool_next_date_of_maintenance* ||
|| 1 || 2014-11-07 || 2015-05-08 ||
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simple update statement with `now`

```
update Table1
set handtool_last_date_of_maintenance = date(now())
where handtool_next_date_of_maintenance = date(now())
```